# A simple recursion equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $L_1=\lceil\log_2x\rceil$ where $x>0$, $L_i = \lceil \log_2L_{i-1} \rceil$ and let $T[1]=1$.

What is the solution for the recursion equation $$T[x]=\sum_{i=1}^{L_1}\frac{xT[L_1-i+1]}{2^i}?$$

Comment: THe word "simple" in the title seems to be out of place here.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy atleast a tight upper bound?

Comment: Among $L_i$ only $L_1$ is used in the definition of $T[x]$.